# firebaseUI Unique transitionNames are required for all sharedElements

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm developing an android app using firebase auth and firebaseUI. My problem is that I can't create a new user via the "Sign in via email" flow. However, when logging in with an existing account everything works fine.

In detail this means the app crashes everytime I click the "Continue" button after entering the email address, with the following error in logcat:

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unique transitionNames are required for all sharedElements
                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.addSharedElement(BackStackRecord.java:511)
                                                                     at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.email.RegisterEmailActivity.onNewUser(RegisterEmailActivity.java:127)
                                                                     at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.email.CheckEmailFragment$2.onSuccess(CheckEmailFragment.java:208)
                                                                     at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.email.CheckEmailFragment$2.onSuccess(CheckEmailFragment.java:204)
                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The problem occurs only since I upgraded 
`com.android.support:support-v4 from 26.1.0 to 27.0.1` and 
`com.google.firebase:firebase-auth from 11.4.2 to 11.6.0` . 
However, I still use `'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'` since I could not find a later version yet.
Could this be an incompatibility of the named libraries or do I miss something? My android version is 4.2.2.

Thank you in advance,
Dan

**UPDATE**
Update to `'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.2'` didn't help. Still the same error which, by the way, does not occur on an api level 25 device.
I had hoped the update would solve the issue but as this doesn't seem to be the case I'm not really sure what to do right now. Any ideas how to troubleshoot this? 
 Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was is solved in `3.1.3`. See also this github [issue](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1036).